# Shaders: Casting float vectors to Structures

Tags: shader, compiler-optimization, hlsl

I know it's possible to cast float vectors such as float3 and float4 to custom structure types, but does anyone know the underlying behavior of the compiler in these situations? The purpose of the casts are strictly for readability and maintainability, so ideally, I would hope that such a cast would do nothing to performance.

Here's an example:

```
StructuredBuffer<float4> Float4Buffer;

...

struct SHADOWTWEAK
{
    float HeightShadowFactor;
    float HeightShadowDepth;
    float HeightAOFactor;
    float HeightAODepth;
};

...

SHADOWTWEAK data = (SHADOWTWEAK) Float4Buffer[ 2 ];

...
```

Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to study the generated compiler code in my current situation, nor am I sure I would be able to make sense of it. Any information about this would be really helpful.